# drawing popOver using core graphics

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

For an iPhone app, I'd like to use popOvers (which are not available for the iPhone) like UIVIews.

Since I started a bit using core graphics (thanks to the wonderful tutorials on ray wenderlich's website), I would love to try to draw them using Core Graphics.

My question is pretty simple : should I just create a class and draw everything inside drawRect, to should I use instances of CALAyers each one dedicated to a particular area of the popOver (one for the arrow, one for the borders, and so on...)? What would be your way of doing it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Check the above git..
Easy way

edit : posted wrong link first..my bad

Comment: Thx @shubhank, but that's the point : just for own knowledge, I'd love to re-invent the wheel ;)